# How to use jquery to insert value to a TextBox depending on another TextBox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using asp.net mvc 3. So far I have managed to create a datepicker. At the moment i have a three fields shown by code below in my view.

```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.QuizNo, new{@class = "qno"}) 
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Mark, new { @class = "mk" })
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pass, new { @class = "ps" })
```

The last one has boolean value. This is my script for changing or setting value in the TextBoxes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   var qn =  $(".qno :input").val();
   $(".mk").val(qn);
   });
 </script>
```

I am testing this to see if when I input a value on the QuizNo textbox I get a value on the Mark textbox. So far its nots happening from the above code.

I am new in asp.net mvc 3 and jquery would like to check the value typed in the QuizNo if its 134, 144 or 156 then any Mark value above 10 is a pass.

Below is the HTML code of the output.

```
<form action="/Home/CreateNewcert/4558" method="post">    <fieldset>
        <legend>CPD Details</legend>
           <table style="border:1px solid #ffffff;">

        <tr>
        <td width="30%" style="border:1px solid #ffffff;">
        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="QuizNo">QuizNo</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">

            <input class="qno" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field QuizNo must be a number." id="QuizNo" name="QuizNo" type="text" value="" /> 
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="QuizNo" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Received">Received</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <select class="list-box tri-state" id="Received" name="Received"><option selected="selected" value="">Not Set</option>
<option value="true">True</option>
<option value="false">False</option>
</select>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Received" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="DateReceived">DateReceived</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="datefield" id="DateReceived" name="DateReceived" type="date" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DateReceived" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Paid">Paid</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <select class="list-box tri-state" id="Paid" name="Paid"><option selected="selected" value="">Not Set</option>
<option value="true">True</option>
<option value="false">False</option>
</select>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Paid" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="DatePaid">DatePaid</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="datefield" id="DatePaid" name="DatePaid" type="date" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DatePaid" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        </td>
          <td width="30%" style="border:1px solid #ffffff;">

        </td>

        <td width="30%" style="border:1px solid #ffffff;">
        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Mark">Mark</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="mk" id="Mark" name="Mark" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Mark" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="MarkDate">MarkDate</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="datefield" id="MarkDate" name="MarkDate" type="date" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="MarkDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Pass">Pass</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <select class="list-box tri-state" id="Pass" name="Pass"><option selected="selected" value="">Not Set</option>
<option value="true">True</option>
<option value="false">False</option>
</select>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Pass" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Printed">Printed</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <select class="list-box tri-state" id="Printed" name="Printed"><option selected="selected" value="">Not Set</option>
<option value="true">True</option>
<option value="false">False</option>
</select>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Printed" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="PrintedDate">PrintedDate</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="datefield" id="PrintedDate" name="PrintedDate" type="date" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="PrintedDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="AccreditationNo">AccreditationNo</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field AccreditationNo must be a number." id="AccreditationNo" name="AccreditationNo" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="AccreditationNo" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        </td></tr></table>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: What's with the cryptic class names?

Comment: nothing wrong with the class names. can you provide the HTML it outputs rather than the script that writes the HTML?

Comment: and how do you show its a pass?

Comment: @popnoodles By changing the not set boolean value to true. This is where I am hearding but hit a brick.

Comment: can you provide the HTML it outputs rather than the script that writes the HTML? The answer lies in javascript/jquery not the language the server is using.

Comment: @popnoodles I have provided the HTML it outputs. I am aware that the answer lies in jquery. My challenge is where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".qno").keyUp(function(){
   $(".mk").val($(this).val());
 });
});
</script>
```